# Нарушение прав доступа чтения памяти при работе с файлом

Tags: c

Я считываю массив структур из файла с помощью `FILE`, `fopen_s`, `fscanf_s`. Первый элемент считывается нормально, а после считывания более чем одной 
структуры перестаёт работать `system()` и выдаёт ошибку при её вызове:

> Вызвано исключение по адресу 0x77BA6F38 (ntdll.dll) в Ito1.exe:
>   0xC0000005: нарушение прав доступа при чтении по адресу 0x00790720.
>   Если для этого исключения имеется обработчик, выполнение программы
>   может быть продолжено безопасно.

Хотя данные нормально записываются в сам массив.

```
 //Зазрузка структуры - place с текстового файла
void loadStruct_place(place &Struct, FILE *saves)
{
    fscanf_s(saves, "%d %d", &Struct.number, &Struct.state);
}


//Загрузка массива структур - place с текстового файла
void loadArrStruct_place(place *arr, int size_arr, FILE *saves)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < size_arr; i++)
    {
        loadStruct_place(arr[i], saves);
    }
}


//Зазрузка структуры - car с текстового файла
void loadStruct_car(car &Struct, FILE *saves)
{
    int size_str = 0;
    fscanf_s(saves, "%d", &size_str);
    size_str++;
    Struct.mark = new char[size_str];
    fscanf_s(saves, "%d\n", &Struct.number);
    fgets(Struct.mark, size_str, saves);
}


//Зазрузка структуры - client с текстового файла
void loadStruct_client(client &Struct, FILE *saves)
{
    int size_str = 0;
    fscanf_s(saves, "%d", &size_str);
    size_str++;
    Struct.name = new char[size_str];
    fscanf_s(saves, "%d\n", &Struct.numberPhone);
    fgets(Struct.name, size_str, saves);
    loadStruct_car(Struct.carClient, saves);
}


//Зазрузка структуры - date с текстового файла
void loadStruct_date(date &Struct, FILE *saves)
{
    fscanf_s(saves, "%d %d %d", &Struct.day, &Struct.month, &Struct.year);
}


//Зазрузка структуры - treaty с текстового файла
void loadStruct_treaty(treaty &Struct, FILE *saves)
{
    loadStruct_client(Struct.clientByTreaty, saves);
    fscanf_s(saves, "%d %d", &Struct.paidDays, &Struct.numberPlace);
    loadStruct_date(Struct.expiredDate, saves);
    loadStruct_date(Struct.datePayment, saves);
}


//Загрузка массива структур - treaty с текстового файла
void loadArrStruct_treaty(treaty *arr, int size_arr, FILE *saves)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < size_arr; i++)
    {
        loadStruct_treaty(arr[i], saves);
    }
}


//Зазрузка структуры - tempTreaty с текстового файла
void loadStruct_tempTreaty(tempTreaty &Struct, FILE *saves)
{
    loadStruct_client(Struct.clientByTreaty, saves);
    fscanf_s(saves, "%d %d %d", &Struct.maxHours, &Struct.paidHours, &Struct.numberPlace);
}


//Загрузка массива структур - tempTreaty с текстового файла
void loadArrStruct_tempTreaty(tempTreaty *arr, int size_arr, FILE *saves)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < size_arr; i++)
    {
        loadStruct_tempTreaty(arr[i], saves);
    }
}


//Зазрузка структуры - parking с текстового файла
void loadStruct_parking(parking &Struct)
{
    FILE *saveParking;

    if (fopen_s(&saveParking, "saves.txt", "r") != NULL)
    {
        cout << "Ошибка!\n";
    }
    else
    {
            fscanf_s(saveParking, "%d", &Struct.size_arr_permanentPlace);
            loadArrStruct_place(Struct.arr_permanentPlace, Struct.size_arr_permanentPlace, saveParking);


            fscanf_s(saveParking, "%d", &Struct.size_arr_guestPlace);
            loadArrStruct_place(Struct.arr_guestPlace, Struct.size_arr_guestPlace, saveParking);


            fscanf_s(saveParking, "%d", &Struct.size_arr_treaty);
            loadArrStruct_treaty(Struct.arr_treaty, Struct.size_arr_treaty, saveParking);


            fscanf_s(saveParking, "%d", &Struct.size_arr_tempTreaty);
            loadArrStruct_tempTreaty(Struct.arr_tempTreaty, Struct.size_arr_tempTreaty, saveParking);
    }
    fclose(saveParking);
    cout << "Капец";
    _getch();
    system("cls");
}
```

Comment: Я предполагаю, что где-то у вас чтение неинициализированного указателя, а system тут ни при чем.

Comment: Походу я читаю в несуществующий элемент массивов treaty и tempTreaty ;), допёр